# Has any of the orbiters or rover on Mars captured image of comet NEOWISE?

Tags: observational-astronomy, solar-system, mars, comets

We are seeing stunning pictures of comet NEOWISE from earth (and ISS too), are there any pictures captured from Mars by an orbiter or rover, or any other spacecraft?

Answer (score 2):

Not yet, as far as I can tell.  The comet looks very different from Mars and while I haven't done the math, I don't think it has an apparent size from the rovers' perspectives to make it look like anything more than a dot.  Since Neowise is moving away from the Sun, the length and brightness of its tail is diminishing rapidly.